# Use of curly braces with object construction

Tags: c#, curly-brackets

Studying Xamarin I've come across this kind of use of curly braces:

```
Label header = new Label
{
    Text = "Label",
    Font = Font.BoldSystemFontOfSize(50),
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
};
```

And I'm wondering how it can be correct because usually in C# when I want to create an instance of an object I do:

```
Label label = new Label();
label.Text = "Label";
...
```

What kind of use of curly brackets is this? How can you create an object without round brackets?

Comment: That is a normal C# 3.0 (or higher) object initialization expression. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738566.aspx for more information.

Comment: There's no difference between the two in terms of functionality.

Comment: Also, you can omit the parenthesis for the constructor **only** if there is a parameterless constructor (or none) for that object. If there are constructors which take parameters, they can be combined with object initializers. The syntax `new Person("John", "Smith") { Address = "123 Main Street" }` is also valid.

Comment: @emodendroket Actually, there is. See my answer.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten OK, fair enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a normal C# 3.0 (or higher) object initialization expression. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738566.aspx for more information.

There is a subtle difference between

```
Label header = new Label
{
    Text = "Label",
};
```

and

```
Label label = new Label();
label.Text = "Label";
```

In the former, when setting the value of a property causes an exception, the variable `header` is not assigned, while as in the latter it is. The reason is that the former is equivalent to:

```
Label temp = new Label();
temp.Text = "Label";
Label label = temp;
```

As you can see, if there is an exception in the second line, the third line never gets executed.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a different syntax for initializing the properties of an object, called [object initializer syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx). It's useful as a way to tell a future developer "this object isn't ready until these properties are set".

This syntax was one of the new features [in C# 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx#csharp3.0overview_topic13), which may be why you're not familiar with it.